# Mongoose : Update not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The basic idea is something like this:

```
model.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        // update it with whatever new object
        model.update({"category":"cat1"});
    });
});
```

Now my question is any sort of update/save doesn't work. I can find, count, etc with the model. I've tried `doc.save()`, `model.findOneAndUpdate()`, using the `$set` parameter for particular fields, they don't work. I went to mongo shell and typed the update command with the parameter, it worked.

One time it did work, was when I tried to put new documents using `var m = new model({..})` and `m.save()` from outside the callback function of `find()`. But I need to find documents by their fields, and update those.

I feel like I'm missing something really elementary, could someone help me out?

edit: mongoose.disconnect() was being called later on in the code. So query did not execute.

Comment: Are you sure the update function is actually being called, like have you put `console.log()` just above the update so you know that line is executing?

Comment: I did, outside the update function with the names of each of the docs just to be sure. And I even put a console.log inside the callback. Funny thing is, the callback is getting executed, but I don't see it reflected in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility cause to this problem is when you use Mixed types, as in `Schema.Types.Mixed`. If you only update the Mixed field, then Mongoose doesn't know you've updated that field. So you need to call [`markModified`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified)

I ran into this recently and it was a pain in the neck to find out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Unless it's just a typo, you're doing an update on the wrong object. You probably want to do</del>

<del>model.find({}, function(err, docs) {
 docs.forEach(function(doc) {
 doc.update({/*fields here*/});
 });
});</del>

Above answer is incorrect.

**Edit**

After thinking a little about it, why are you doing `find` at all? You should be able to update your docoments without it. Check the [API docs for update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)

```
model.update({}, {field1: 'updated value'}, function(err) {});
```

Comment: That's right, but I'm not able to do it within the callback. I put the update code outside the find({}) callback with some random values, and it works just fine. Is updating this way undoable in mongoose? I'm still quite new to it.

Comment: When I think of it, why are you doing find at all? You should be able to just call `update` with the correct parameters.

Comment: Because I'm modifying each doc. Say for example, doc.value = oldvalue++. So I figured I had to get each doc, modify as needed and push the new doc into the db.

Comment: Aha! I'm starting to understand what you're trying to do. If it's a simple addition you need, check the [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/#op._S_inc) update operator. If you're looking for more complex computations, there seems to be some [work going on](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I finally got it. Embarrassed to say it, but I was calling mongoose.disconnect() in the function, so the connection to the db was getting cut before the query got a chance to execute.